# how to implement pagination front-end in spring boot web application using jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, pagination

I have read many pagination examples and almost all of them are as Rest Services I did not find any example which is implemented as web page front-end. So till now, I have learned how to implement pagination at the back-end. I have proper methods in `Controller`, `Service`, `Repository` and I'm getting the resulted values from the database(MySQL).
My repository extends the JpaRepository and I'm implementing the pagination with pageable. Below are the method in my Controller, Service, Repository.

In Repository class

```
Page<SlUrl> findAllByOrderByCreationDateDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

In Service class (subtractPageByOne is because index start from 0 but the url parameter will start from 1)

```
public Page<SlUrl> getUrlsByPage(int pageNumber, int numberOfElementsPerPage) {

        return urlRepository.findAllByOrderByCreationDateDesc(PageRequest.of(subtractPageByOne(pageNumber), numberOfElementsPerPage));
    }

    private int subtractPageByOne(int page) {
        return (page < 1) ? 0 : page - 1;
    }
```

And in Controller class

```
@GetMapping("/urls")
    public ModelAndView openPageableUrls(ModelAndView mv, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
        System.out.println("Inside /urls");
        Page<SlUrl> urls = slUrlService.getUrlsByPage(page, 5);
        List<SlUrl> urlList = urls.getContent();
        System.out.println("Url count = " + urls.getSize()
                + " Number = " + urls.getNumber() + "");

        mv.setViewName("userlinks");

        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\nURLs Details:"
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getId()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getDestinationUrlLink()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getShortUrlLink()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getUser().getUsername());
        }

        return mv;
    }
```

You can see that I have a `for` loop to show the detail of SlUrl it's working fine. Now my question is what is the best way to show the above details on the front-end (JSP page). One way I think of is passing this `urlList` and use the for-each loop to show the data. But this data is just for example purpose what if I have to implement something like blog or to show version history.

So how to best represent the data at the front-end. A code example would be very helpful.

Comment: What are you struggling with? Just add the page to the model, e.g. `mv.getModelMap().addAttribute("page", urls)` and loop through the content in the JSP with `page.content`. That gives you access to `page.totalPages` and `page.totalElements` as well.

Comment: How to implement the next and previous button? what `href` to give to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for the other users that may come to this post.
I found [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/reljicd/spring-boot-blog) that implements the pagination but that is using `thymeleaf` template instead of JSP pages. So, from that repository, I have built the pagination for JSP pages.

Here is the Pager util class that gives all info about pages

```
package packageNameHere;


import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

/**
 * @author Inzimam Tariq
 */
public class Pager {

    private final Page<SlUrl> urls;

    public Pager(Page<SlUrl> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    public int getPageIndex() {
        return urls.getNumber() + 1;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return urls.getSize();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return urls.hasNext();
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return urls.hasPrevious();
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return urls.getTotalPages();
    }

    public long getTotalElements() {
        return urls.getTotalElements();
    }

    public Page<SlUrl> getSlUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public boolean indexOutOfBounds() {
        return getPageIndex() < 0 || getPageIndex() > getTotalElements();
    }

}
```

Now in controller I'm passing page and pager info to ModelAndView. The whole method look like this

```
@GetMapping("/urls")
    public ModelAndView openPageableUrls(ModelAndView mv, HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
        System.out.println("Inside /urls");
        Page<SlUrl> urls = slUrlService.getUrlsByPage(page, 5);
        List<SlUrl> urlList = urls.getContent();
        System.out.println("Url count = " + urls.getSize()
                + " Number = " + urls.getNumber() + " Elements = " + urls.getNumberOfElements());
        Pager pager = new Pager(urls);

        mv.addObject("baseUrl", AppUtils.getBaseUrl(request));
        mv.addObject("pager", pager);
        urls.getTotalPages();
        mv.addObject("page", urls);
        mv.setViewName("pagination");

        for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\nURLs Details:"
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getId()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getDestinationUrlLink()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getShortUrlLink()
                    + "\nid = " + urlList.get(i).getUser().getUsername());
        }

        return mv;
    }
```

And here is my pagination.jsp page where I'm looping through the data (in this case URLs)

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><br>
     <h1 class="display-4 d-md-display-4"><b>Title_Here</b></h1>
     <p>This is a long test text for demo paragraph.</p>

     <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style='vertical-align:middle'>
         <thead class="thead-dark">
             <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Destination Url</th>
                <th>Short URL</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="links" items="${page.content}">
                <tr>
                <td>${links.getId()}</td>
                <td>${links.getDestinationUrlLink()}</td>
                <td>${links.getShortUrlLink()}</td>
                <td id="copyTd_${links.getId()}" hidden="">
                    <input type="text" id="${links.getId()}" value="${baseUrl}/${links.getShortUrlLink()}">
                </td>
                <td><button type="submit" id="copy_${links.getId()}" 
                           class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
                                                        onclick="copyShortLink(${links.getId()})"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to copy shortlink!">
                      Copy
                    </button>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
   </table>                   

   <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
      <c:if test="${pager.hasPrevious()}">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="margin: 2px"
                   onclick="location.href = 'urls?page=1'">&laquo; first</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="margin: 2px"
                    onclick="location.href = 'urls?page=${pager.getPageIndex() - 1}'">previous</button>
      </c:if>

      <c:if test="${pager.getTotalPages() != 1}">
            <label style="margin: 2px 8px 2px 8px">
                   Page ${pager.getPageIndex()} of  ${pager.getTotalPages()}
            </label>
      </c:if>

      <c:if test="${pager.hasNext()}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="margin: 2px"
                   onclick="location.href = 'urls?page=${pager.getPageIndex() + 1}'">next</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="margin: 2px"
                   onclick="location.href = 'urls?page=${pager.getTotalPages()}'">last &raquo;</button>                                    
      </c:if>
    </div>

</div>
```